# Maze generation and unicode characters

Tags: c++, unicode, maze

I am new to c++ and need help making my maze look better. I want to use unicode characters but my program crashes. Here is a picture of my random maze. [image of my maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4h0t.jpg)

You can check my code here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::fill;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

    int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int arr_x[1000] = { 0 }; fill(arr_x + 0, arr_x + 1000, -1);
        int arr_y[1000] = { 0 }; fill(arr_y + 0, arr_y + 1000, -1);
//coordinates used to go back when the generation runs into blocked path 


        char arr[100][100]; memset(arr, '#', sizeof(char) * 100 * 100);
    //creating 100x100 char array of #
        int rows, cols = 0;
        cout << "Rows "; cin >> rows;//choose 
        cout << "Columns"; cin >> cols;

        int random_number = 0; int x = 0; int y = 0; int index = 0;
        arr[0][0] = ' ';

        while (1)
        {

            random_number = rand() % (4) + 1;
            int available_paths = 0;
            if (x + 1 >= 0 && x + 1 < rows && arr[x + 1][y] != ' ' && arr[x + 2][y] != ' ' && arr[x + 1][y + 1] != ' ' && arr[x + 1][y - 1] != ' ') { available_paths++; if (random_number == 1) { x = x + 1; arr_x[index] = x; arr_y[index] = y; arr[x][y] = ' '; index++; } }
            if (x - 1 >= 0 && x - 1 < rows && arr[x - 1][y] != ' ' && arr[x - 2][y] != ' ' && arr[x - 1][y + 1] != ' ' && arr[x - 1][y - 1] != ' ') { available_paths++; if (random_number == 2) { x = x - 1; arr_x[index] = x; arr_y[index] = y; arr[x][y] = ' '; index++; } }
            if (y + 1 >= 0 && y + 1 < cols && arr[x][y + 1] != ' ' && arr[x][y + 2] != ' ' && arr[x + 1][y + 1] != ' ' && arr[x - 1][y + 1] != ' ') { available_paths++; if (random_number == 3) { y = y + 1; arr_x[index] = x; arr_y[index] = y; arr[x][y] = ' '; index++; } }
            if (y - 1 >= 0 && y - 1 < cols && arr[x][y - 1] != ' ' && arr[x][y - 2] != ' ' && arr[x + 1][y - 1] != ' ' && arr[x - 1][y - 1] != ' ') { available_paths++; if (random_number == 4) { y = y - 1; arr_x[index] = x; arr_y[index] = y; arr[x][y] = ' '; index++; } }
            if (available_paths == 0) //if available_paths are 0 I need to go 
            {                         //back to the last visited square
                index = index - 1;
                if (index < 0) { break; }
                x = arr_x[index]; y = arr_y[index];
            }
        }


        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
            {
                cout << "[" << arr[x][y] << "]";
                if (y == (cols - 1)) { cout << endl; }
            }
        }

        int end;
        cin >> end;
    }
```

I am thinking about using this character - ▮. Is there any simple way to improve my algorithm?

Comment: "I want to use unicode characters" `wchar_t` and `std::wcout` will likely help here.

Comment: AFAIK the console only knows about the user "code-page" (windows parlance), nothing about Unicode.

Comment: There are many ways to improve your algorithm. For starters, get rid of the duplicated code. There are two copies of identical logic that checks for available/blocked paths. Duplicated code is a fertile spawning ground for bugs. Refactor it properly, so the available paths are checked and chosen just once. Then, you can get rid of all the magical constants. Magical constants are another fertile ground for bug spawning. Your logic should be able to correctly handle a maze of any dimension, with the horizontal and vertical dimensions specified exactly once. Good luck.

Comment: You may want to perform an exercise and see if you can rewrite your code without `goto`.